# Is there a command in PostgreSQL that can find if a tuple "contains" a specific value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, contains

For example:

How do i find if the word: "hello" was in the column "greetings"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tab where col1 LIKE '%help%' OR col2 LIKE '%hello%'
```

and so on...